# JSONPath for the JSON

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the below JSON

```
 {
  "RestResponse": {
    "messages": [
        "Total [36] records found."
    ],
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 56,
            "country": "IND",
            "name": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "abbr": "AP",
            "area": "49506799SKM",
            "largest_city": "Hyderabad Amaravati",
            "capital": "Hyderabad Amaravati"
        }
    ]
   }
 }
```

To access the name I am trying to give the JSONPath as

```
 $RestResponse.result[*].name
```

also as

```
 $RestResponse.result[:1].name
```

Both seems to be not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to `$.RestResponse.result[*].name`.  The dot notation is important from the root element *$*, as in every other part of the jsonpath query.

Answer (score 0):

> JSONPath expressions can use the dot–notation or the bracket–notation
>   for input pathes. [Learn JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

- **bracket–notation**

  $['RestResponse']['result'][0]['name']
- **dot–notation**

  $.RestResponse.result[0].name

You can try JsonPath Expression Tester [here](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)